# d3 multiline voronoi not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I created a multi-line chart but I have been struggling to add a voronoi for better mouse interactions. Any help to point me to the right direction would be much appreciated.

Here's my data:

```
U.S. Custom Ports,Coast,Year,Value
"Aberdeen, WA",P,1997,0
"Aberdeen, WA",P,1998,24
"Aberdeen, WA",P,1999,3284.95
"Aberdeen, WA",P,2000,0
"Aberdeen, WA",P,2001,78.83
"Aberdeen, WA",P,2002,75.16
"Aberdeen, WA",P,2003,0
"Aberdeen, WA",P,2004,0
"Aberdeen, WA",P,2005,194.35
"Aberdeen, WA",P,2006,0
"Aberdeen, WA",P,2007,0
"Aberdeen, WA",P,2008,0
"Aberdeen, WA",P,2009,45.14
"Aberdeen, WA",P,2010,303
"Aberdeen, WA",P,2011,680.42
"Aberdeen, WA",P,2012,437.43
"Aberdeen, WA",P,2013,2436.97
"Aberdeen, WA",P,2014,894.86
"Anacortes, WA",P,1997,0
"Anacortes, WA",P,1998,0
"Anacortes, WA",P,1999,0
"Anacortes, WA",P,2000,0
"Anacortes, WA",P,2001,0
"Anacortes, WA",P,2002,0
"Anacortes, WA",P,2003,0
"Anacortes, WA",P,2004,0
"Anacortes, WA",P,2005,0
```

Here's my code:

```
function drawMultiLine(){

      var container = d3.select('#g-multiline');

      var margin = {top:10, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 30},
      width = 300 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 550 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      var parseYear = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;


      var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
      var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
          .orient("bottom")
          .ticks(2)

      var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
          .orient("right").ticks(4)

      var valueline = d3.svg.line()
        // .interpolate("basis") 
        .interpolate("step-before")
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.Year); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.Value); });

      var g = container
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append('g')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      function make_x_axis() { return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(5)
      }
      function make_y_axis() { return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(10)
      }

      var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.Year); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.Value); })
        .clipExtent([[-margin.left, -margin.top], [width + margin.right, height + margin.bottom]]);

      d3.csv("../../data/container_data.csv", function(error,data){
        if (error) throw error; 

        data.forEach(function(d) {
          d.Year = parseYear(d.Year);
          d.Value = +d.Value;
        });

        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Year; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Value; })]); 

        g.append("g")
          .attr("class", "xgrid")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(make_x_axis()
              .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)

          )
        g.append("g")
          .attr("class", "ygrid")
          .call(make_y_axis()
              .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
              .ticks(5)
              .tickFormat(d3.format("s"))
          )

        g.append("g")         // Add the X Axis
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

        g.append("g")         // Add the Y Axis
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
          .append("text")
          .attr("y", 80)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("Tons");


         // Nest the entries by port name
        var dataNest = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d){return d["U.S. Custom Ports"]})
            .entries(data);

        g.append("rect")
              .attr("x", 110)
              .attr("y", 0)
              .attr("width", "5%")
              .attr("height", height)
              .attr("class","recession")

        dataNest
          .forEach(function(d) {
            g.append("path")
              .attr("class", "line")
              .attr("d", valueline(d.values))
              // .attr("class",d.key, "line")
        });

        var focus = g.append("g")
          .attr("class", "focus")
          .attr("transform", "translate(-100,-100)");

        focus.append("circle")
          .attr("r", 4);

        var voronoiGroup = g.append("g")
          .attr("class", "voronoi");

        voronoiGroup.selectAll("path")
          .data(voronoi(dataNest))
          .enter().append("path")
          .attr("d", function(d) { return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z"; })
          .datum(function(d) { return d.point; })


      })
    }

drawMultiLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the `voronoi` function an array of nested objects.  This is incorrect, as it's [expecting a flat array of data](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Voronoi-Geom#_voronoi).  The simplest fix to flatten your is:

```
var vd = [];
dataNest.forEach(function(d){
  vd = vd.concat(d.values);
});

voronoiGroup.selectAll("path")
  .data(voronoi(vd))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    if (d) return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z";
   })
   .datum(function(d) {
      if (d) return d.point;
   });
```

---

Working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <style>
    path {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
    }
    
    rect {
      fill: orange;
    }
    
    .voronoi path {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="g-multiline"></div>
  <script>
    function drawMultiLine() {

      var container = d3.select('#g-multiline');

      var margin = {
          top: 10,
          right: 80,
          bottom: 30,
          left: 30
        },
        width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 550 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      var parseYear = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;


      var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
      var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(2)

      var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
        .orient("right").ticks(4)

      var valueline = d3.svg.line()
        // .interpolate("basis") 
        .interpolate("step-before")
        .x(function(d) {
          return x(d.Year);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return y(d.Value);
        });

      var g = container
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append('g')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      function make_x_axis() {
        return d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(x)
          .orient("bottom")
          .ticks(5)
      }

      function make_y_axis() {
        return d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(y)
          .orient("left")
          .ticks(10)
      }

      var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
        .x(function(d) {
          return x(d.Year);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return y(d.Value);
        })
        .clipExtent([
          [-margin.left, -margin.top],
          [width + margin.right, height + margin.bottom]
        ]);

      //d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
        var data = [{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Aberdeen, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"1997","Value":"0"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Aberdeen, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"1998","Value":"24"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Aberdeen, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"1999","Value":"3284.95"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Aberdeen, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"2000","Value":"0"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Aberdeen, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"2001","Value":"78.83"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Aberdeen, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"2002","Value":"75.16"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Aberdeen, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"2003","Value":"0"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Aberdeen, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"2004","Value":"0"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Aberdeen, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"2005","Value":"194.35"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Aberdeen, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"2006","Value":"0"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Aberdeen, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"2007","Value":"0"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Aberdeen, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"2008","Value":"0"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Aberdeen, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"2009","Value":"45.14"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Aberdeen, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"2010","Value":"303"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Aberdeen, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"2011","Value":"680.42"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Aberdeen, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"2012","Value":"437.43"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Aberdeen, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"2013","Value":"2436.97"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Aberdeen, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"2014","Value":"894.86"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Anacortes, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"1997","Value":"0"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Anacortes, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"1998","Value":"0"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Anacortes, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"1999","Value":"0"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Anacortes, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"2000","Value":"0"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Anacortes, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"2001","Value":"0"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Anacortes, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"2002","Value":"0"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Anacortes, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"2003","Value":"0"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Anacortes, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"2004","Value":"0"},{"U.S. Custom Ports":"Anacortes, WA","Coast":"P","Year":"2005","Value":"0"}];

        data.forEach(function(d) {
          d.Year = parseYear(d.Year);
          d.Value = +d.Value;
        });

        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
          return d.Year;
        }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
          return d.Value;
        })]);

        g.append("g")
          .attr("class", "xgrid")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(make_x_axis()
            .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)

          )
        g.append("g")
          .attr("class", "ygrid")
          .call(make_y_axis()
            .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
            .ticks(5)
            .tickFormat(d3.format("s"))
          )

        g.append("g") // Add the X Axis
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

        g.append("g") // Add the Y Axis
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
          .append("text")
          .attr("y", 80)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("Tons");


        // Nest the entries by port name
        var dataNest = d3.nest()
          .key(function(d) {
            return d["U.S. Custom Ports"]
          })
          .entries(data);

        g.append("rect")
          .attr("x", 110)
          .attr("y", 0)
          .attr("width", "5%")
          .attr("height", height)
          .attr("class", "recession")

        dataNest
          .forEach(function(d) {
            g.append("path")
              .attr("class", "line")
              .attr("d", valueline(d.values))
              .attr("id", d.key.replace(/, /, ''))
          });

        var focus = g.append("g")
          .attr("class", "focus")
          .attr("transform", "translate(-100,-100)");

        focus.append("circle")
          .attr("r", 4);

        var voronoiGroup = g.append("g")
          .attr("class", "voronoi");
        
        var vd = [];
        dataNest.forEach(function(d){
          console.log(d);
          vd = vd.concat(d.values);
        })

        voronoiGroup.selectAll("path")
          .data(voronoi(vd))
          .enter().append("path")
          .attr("d", function(d) {
            if (d) return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z";
          })
          .datum(function(d) {
            if (d) return d.point;
          })
          .on("mouseover", function(d){
            var key = d["U.S. Custom Ports"].replace(/, /,'');
            d3.select('#' + key)
              .style("stroke", "green");
          })
          .on("mouseout", function(d){
            var key = d["U.S. Custom Ports"].replace(/, /,'');
            d3.select('#' + key)
              .style("stroke", "steelblue");
          })


     // })
    }

    drawMultiLine();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Whoa, thanks Mark, that's super helpful. I do have one quick question, I am trying to add mouseover/mouseout functions to change line color.....But so far I have no luck making mouseover to correspond my lines. I am pretty sure is my d3 selection that's causing the problem but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: so sorry about bugging you again. I tired the snippet above but still had no luck getting hover color to work.I'm so confused. I uploaded my code to bl.ocks, it'd be extremeley helpful if you could kindly direct me to the right direction: http://blockbuilder.org/jeremycflin/a304ed19652fee4cfbe58bc9c0afa2ec

Comment: @fabrice, see it here: http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/d097eb132f5b46a3f22315d760f87242, you were missing some css (pointer events on the voronoi) and assigned a unique id to each line.